# Fast calculation of $\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{v}$

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

I'm doing some numerics (related to Gaussian processes) and need to calculate the matrix multiplication $\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{v}\ $ as fast as possible. An implementation I am looking at finds the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$ and then uses that to calculate $\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{v}\ $ which should be $\mathcal{O} (n^3)$ (coming from the Cholesky). I wanted to know if there is a faster (but still stable) way? I know for example that matrix inversion itself can be done in less than $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

EDIT: Will also need to calculate $Tr(\Sigma^{-1} M)$ for a matrix $M$.

Comment: What is the structure of Σ? Size, sparsity, symmetric, positive definite? Does it have to be exact? How often do you need to compute that multiplication?

Comment: It's a covariance matrix. I have noticed I will also need to be calculating $Tr (\Sigma^{-1} M)$ where $M$ is another matrix and so ideally the method should cover that as well

Comment: I believe that if you use a quantum computer, there are algorithms that you could do this very efficiently with! But that doesn't answer your question right now. (The algorithms exist, but not the computers)

Comment: Solving a linear system using the existing factorization should be $O(n^2)$, so that only the multiplication of the inverse with a quadratic matrix is again $O(n^3)$. Computing the factorization itself is $O(n^3)$.